# Add multiple arguments inside a function to return a specified class in python

Tags: python, graph-theory

In `python`, I created the following classes in order to create the **map of a town** with *n* locations (a location can be connected to another by a road with the specified duration on the third argument of the tuple : `[tuple[Emplacement, Emplacement, float]`

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Emplacement:
    """Représente un emplacement de la ville."""

    nom: int

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nom)


@dataclass
class Itineraire:
    """Représente l'itinéraire qu'un client souhaite emprunter"""

    etapes: list[Emplacement]


@dataclass
class Ville:
    """Représentation de la carte de la ville."""

    emplacements: list[Emplacement]
    arretes: list[tuple[Emplacement, Emplacement, float]]

    def __post_init__(self):
        if any(poids <= 0 for _, _, poids in self.arretes):
            raise ValueError("Les durées des trajets sont forcément positives!")

        for depart, arrivee, _ in self.arretes:
            if depart not in self.emplacements:
                raise ValueError(f"L'emplacement {depart} n'existe pas dans la ville !")
            if arrivee not in self.emplacements:
                raise ValueError(
                    f"L'emplacement {arrivee} n'existe pas dans la ville !"
                )
```

Once the classes were set, I created a function  to generate a map with 16 all-interconnected locations (which is in fact a **weighted graph**)

```py
def _constructeur_ville():
    (e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,e_6,e_7,e_8,e_9,e_10,e_11,e_12,e_13,e_14,e_15,e_16,) = emplacements = [
        Emplacement(nom=1),
        Emplacement(nom=2),
        Emplacement(nom=3),
        Emplacement(nom=4),
        Emplacement(nom=5),
        Emplacement(nom=6),
        Emplacement(nom=7),
        Emplacement(nom=8),
        Emplacement(nom=9),
        Emplacement(nom=10),
        Emplacement(nom=11),
        Emplacement(nom=12),
        Emplacement(nom=13),
        Emplacement(nom=14),
        Emplacement(nom=15),
        Emplacement(nom=16),
    ]
    return Ville(
        emplacements=emplacements,
        arretes=[
            (e_1, e_2, 5),
            (e_1, e_3, 9),
            (e_1, e_4, 4),
            (e_2, e_5, 3),
            (e_2, e_6, 2),
            (e_3, e_4, 4),
            (e_3, e_6, 1),
            (e_4, e_7, 7),
            (e_5, e_8, 4),
            (e_5, e_9, 2),
            (e_5, e_10, 9),
            (e_6, e_7, 3),
            (e_6, e_10, 9),
            (e_6, e_11, 6),
            (e_7, e_11, 8),
            (e_7, e_15, 5),
            (e_8, e_12, 5),
            (e_9, e_8, 3),
            (e_9, e_13, 10),
            (e_10, e_9, 6),
            (e_10, e_13, 5),
            (e_10, e_14, 1),
            (e_11, e_14, 2),
            (e_12, e_16, 9),
            (e_13, e_12, 4),
            (e_13, e_14, 3),
            (e_14, e_16, 4),
            (e_15, e_14, 4),
            (e_15, e_16, 3),
        ],
    )


CARTE_VILLE = _constructeur_ville()
```

Everything works perfectly as of now, but I also want to add an argument inside the `_constructeur_ville()` function to allow the user to add more or less duration to the duration value of any edge.

- For instance, let's take `(e_9, e_13, 10)` and let's imagine that the user wants to add +2 or -2 minutes to that edge duration.

Since the values are stored inside a tuple, I cant modify them after the creation of the object, hence I need to do it inside the function.

Any idea ?

Comment: Function `_constructeur_ville` returns a list, and although you can't modify a tuple, you can modify the list. For instance `i = next(i for i,(u,v,d) in enumerate(CARTE_VILLE) if (u,v) == (e_9, e13)); u,v,d = CARTE_VILLE[i]; CARTE_VILLE[i] = (u,v,d+2)`

Answer (score 0):

The final answer is an adaptation of what @Stef proposed :

```py
def genere_bouchons(
    depart: Emplacement, arrivee: Emplacement, duree: float, ville: Ville
) -> Ville:
    """Génère des bouchons à partir d'une arrête et d'une durée spécifiée."""
    if all(depart != emplacement for emplacement in ville.emplacements):
        raise EmplacementInconnu(
            f"Attention, {depart} n'est pas un emplacement valide !"
        )
    if all(arrivee != emplacement for emplacement in ville.emplacements):
        raise EmplacementInconnu(
            f"Attention, {arrivee} n'est pas un emplacement valide !"
        )
    if depart == arrivee:
        raise MemeEmplacement(
            "Attention, vous n'avez pas sélectionné une route, mais un emplacement de la ville!"
        )
    try:
        i = next(
            i
            for i, (u, v, d) in enumerate(ville.arretes)
            if (u.nom == depart.nom and v.nom == arrivee.nom)
            or (v.nom == depart.nom and u.nom == arrivee.nom)
        )
    except StopIteration as e:
        raise ArreteInexistante(
            f"La route spécifiée entre les emplacements {depart} et {arrivee} n'existe pas !"
        )
    else:
        u, v, d = ville.arretes[i]

        if (d + duree) <= 0:
            raise DureeNegative(
                "Attention, la durée de la fluidification spécifiée ne respecte pas les durées de trajets réels !"
            )
        ville.arretes[i] = (u, v, d + duree)
    return ville.arretes[i]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).